# How to use ajax and jquery in jsp

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

Here is my code:

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
 url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/demo"
 user="root"  password="root"/>

 <sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="list">
  SELECT * from EmoloyeeSample;
</sql:query>
<form action="some.jsp" method="get">
<select name="id" id="name" onkeyup="doSomething(this.value);">

     <option value="0">Select an Employee</option>
   <c:forEach var="employee" items="${list.rows}">
   <option value="${employee.id}">${employee.name}</option>
    </c:forEach>


</select>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" >

 <script>
 $(function() {
 var availableTags=${list}
 $( "#name" ).autocomplete({
   source: availableTags
 });
});
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I am getting values from database in ${list} and all values are shown in Drop down list but my requirment is that when user press s then only name having initial as s must be shown in drop down list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a datalist as [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist)

Please consider that if the number of field is huge than this might not be a good solution